# How to keep output window always open in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, output-window

I am developing C# Windows Forms App, and need to output some debug message using `Debug.Print()`. However, the output window is always being minimised on each new debug session. How do I keep it dock'ed to the window so I don't have to click it every single time?

Also, how can I reset the window layout in coding and debugging mode separately? Especially the debugging mode, it seems not saving the layout...

I found similar questions about opening the output window during building, but couldn't find any reference on debugging.

---- update

Thanks for the contributions. Although it was not the solution. I tried to reset the layout again and a few times and it now works fine. It was weird that it wasn't working.

Since no one submitted the solution and I am still expecting if anyone knows the cause and solution, I am leaving this question open without accepting any of the answers.

Thanks again.

2017.08.03.

Comment: Debug saves layout for me

Comment: @EpicKip I wish it would save for me as well, but it doesn't. I don't know if it was any problem with my settings or some bugs. Any idea of how to reset it?

Comment: Just wondering if you have a problem with docking/pinning.  If you are debugging and you open the output window, and then click on some code ( a text window ), does the output window go away?

Comment: @Derek It wasn't pinned once debugging starts, but I can pin. After pinning, the output window will not go away, until I stop the current debugging and start another session. By then, it will hide automatically.

Answer (score 20):

Go to "Tools" -> "Options..." and under the "Projects and Solutions" tab 
expander, you can find a checkbox labeled "Show Output window when build starts". Check it to enable the output window/pane to appear automatically when you build your project. Keep it unchecked, if you don't want to open it automatically.

[image]

Comment: As I said, I know this solution to bring the window up during **building**, but I need to bring the output once build finishes and start **debugging**. With your approach, the output just collapses again once build finishes.

Comment: Hi @TideGu Just make sure you have disable auto hide option in out put window. its placed at left side of close option of output windows.

Answer (score 2):

I also had similar weird behavior after last VS 2017 update (I applied that update a couple days ago and also had output window autohide behavior - it's very annoying!).

I tried everything (nothing helps) but ended up with unchecking "Automatically adjust visual experience based on client performance" check box at Options->Environment->General.

Hope, this will help.

Comment: Thanks. I will test this if I face the same issue next time. Sorry I can't mark this as an accepted answer before actually tested it or other members can confirm this. I have upvoted though. If anyone else can confirm this, I would be more than happy to accept this answer. Many thanks again for your output!

Comment: Not a problem, I'm answering not for the points but to help people :)

Comment: This does not answer the actual question being asked at all.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the "Output" tool window setting under Help -> "Manage Visual Studio Performance"?

This value was set to "Auto hide window at startup" on my machine, causing the output window (and all other windows docked in the same region) to be collapsed every time I started visual studio. Maybe this is actually your problem?

Set it to "Use default behaviour" to tell visual studio to leave it alone.

Comment: I only have error list window set to auto hide (I didn't do it myself). Maybe it was in the same pane... Thanks!